# Good way to integrate C++ App Server with C# Web Service (Client+Server)

Tags: c#, c++, web-services

I have WSDL of remote web service and WSDL of server.
I have C++ application server too and i must integrate this Web Service
Client and Server with C++ POSIX server daemon.

I will implement web services in C#.
I integrate web service server with C++ server with XML protocol over TCP/IP
But what is good solution for integrate c++ server with Web Service client?

I think implementing SOAP web service or using some stuff for it is not good idea on C++ side,
then how to good integrate c++ with C# web service client.

Best way is setup C# windows service server for creating requests via Web Service?
This C# server will get commands over XML from C++ server.

Greetings,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at "gSOAP Toolkit" (http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html)